# Rebooting problem

Tags: 12.04, graphics

After restarting my ubuntu PC, I am getting a dialog window showing "Your system is running in low graphics mode" and after clicking on 'OK', I was prompted with three options 
  1. Run in low graphics mode for just one session
  2. Reconfigure graphics
  3. Troubleshoot the error
  4. Exit to console login

When I troubleshoot the error, its showing the black screen with following lines which I remember:

we do not own /var/log/pm-powersave.log
   .......................................
   couldn't write bytes: Broken pipe
   .......................................
   .......................................
   Starting System V runlevel compatibility

got strucked at this point.

Actually before restarting, I have changed the owner for all the files under the directory "/var/log" and "/var/lib". Is there any relation with the above issue. Please help me out to resolve the issue. Its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

It could be quite possible depending on what you changed the permissions to, have you considered:

`sudo chmod -R 775 /var/` or `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/*`

Comment: I used this following two commands: sudo chown $USER /var/log and sudo chown $USER /var/lib

Comment: Change ownership? `sudo chown -hR <username> /var/log`

Comment: you want me to change the ownership back?

Comment: Oops, misread; though the -R recursive option might prove useful for all the log files to be within your ownership?

Comment: I have no idea. Initially "/var/log" and "/var/lib" were under root directory. I logged as user "vinoth", also I dont have access to create or delete the files under these directories so I executed these above commands. My intention is to know whether these changes is affecting to prompt this window "Your system is running in low graphics mode"?

Comment: It labels the log errors as pm-powersave.log, powersave allows power saving by reducing things such as disk-activity, filesystem alterations etcetc. Try turning it off with: `sudo pm-powersave false` or on if it's already off with `sudo pm-powersave true`; see if it affects you at all.

Comment: what will happen if I execute these commands "sudo pm-powersave false" and "sudo pm-powersave true" ? And also if I execute any sudo** command, am prompting with "sudo:/var/lb/sudo/vinoth owned by uid 1002, should be uid 0" before entering password.